# How can I set a widescreen resolution?

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals

I am trying to play *Command & Conquer: Generals* on a laptop with a native resolution of 1600x900 but the game doesn't appear to support any custom or widescreen resolutions. All of the resolutions in game appear to have an aspect ratio of 4:3, leaving large black bars down either side of the screen.

How do you run *Command & Conquer: Generals* in a custom widescreen resolution?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order to set a custom resolution, simply perform the following steps;

- Start the game for the first time
- Change the resolution from the default 800x600
- Exit the game
- Inside your My Documents folder, you will find a `Command and Conquer Generals Data` folder
- Inside this folder you will find a file called `Options.ini`, edit this file
- Find the line that says `Resolution =` and change the value from whatever it is to whatever you want

For example, for a resolution of 1600x900, you will want to set the `Resolution =` line to `Resolution = 1600 900`.

Comment: You can also change the view height in that file, which is very nice. Also note that if use the ingame settings to change anything after doing this, it will reset to 800x600.

Comment: what setting(s) do I have to change to adjust the view height?

Comment: The setting is called `maxcameraheight`. I think I normally set it to 800. Too high, and you'll be able to see the edges of the loaded map area.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can modify shortcut path.

Something like this (for full hd resolution):

> "C:\Program Files\EA Games\Command & Conquer Generals Zero Hour\generals.exe" -win -xres 1920 -yres 1080

you can also add command `-quickstart` for skip intro playing every time... or `-win` for run game in windowed mode...

Comment: This works!
MacBook Pro 16" 2019